# Inheritance and accessing parent class in unbound method in python

Tags: python, inheritance

I have this class with an unbound method and a static class inside:

```
class ClassA():
    class Foo():
        pass

    def getFoo():
        return ???.Foo
```

Now, if I inherit a ClassB from ClassA how do I get ClassB.getFoo() to return ClassB.Foo without explicitly implementing ClassB.getFoo()? Returning `super().Foo` doesn't work, writing `ClassA.Foo` doesn't work either obviously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getFoo` should be a classmethod:

```
class ClassA():
    class Foo():
        pass

    @classmethod
    def getFoo(cls):
        return cls.Foo
```

Class methods are passed their class as their first argument, similar to how instance methods are passed the instance as the first argument.  When you subclass ClassA, the proper class is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my own thoughts on this: In addition to @Ned Batchelder's answer, you can use static methods to achieve a similar goal.

```
class ClassA():
    class Foo():
       def fooTest(self):
         print("Hello from {}!".format(self.__name__))

  @staticmethod
  def getFoo():
    return ClassA.Foo

class ClassB(ClassA):
    pass
```

And test with:

```
>>> Foo = ClassB.getFoo()
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.fooTest()
Hello from Foo!
```

This to me demonstrates the beauty of the python language - there are usually multiple ways of solving the same problem...